# Получить id пользователя node.js

Tags: node.js, socket.io, сессия, php, mysql

Вопрос очень простой как узнать id вошедшего пользователя из node.js. На сайте регистрация php + mysql. Нужно для написания чата.

Вот код серверной части, подскажите пожалуйста что не так, или покажите на примере как это можно сделать.

```
var http = require('http');

var mysql      = require('mysql');

var connection = mysql.createConnection({
host     : 'localhost',
user     : 'root',
password : '',
port: '3306',
database : 'test',
});

var io = require('socket.io').listen(8080);

io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {

socket.on('connect_user', function(login,password, idUserGet){
var sql    = 'SELECT * FROM users WHERE login = ' + connection.escape(login) + ' AND               password = ' + connection.escape(password) + ' ';
connection.query(sql, function(err, rows) {
    if(rows.length > 0) {

        socket.userGet = idUserGet;
        socket.userSend = rows[0].id;

        console.log(socket.userSend+' has been logined ');
        socket.join(socket.userSend);

        // Мое имя.
        socket.user = rows[0].login;
    } 
});

socket.on( 'msg', function(msg) {
// htmlencode
msg = escapeHtml(msg);

// Unixtime
milliseconds = parseInt(new Date().getTime()/1000);
var post  = {user_send: socket.userSend, user_get: socket.userGet, text: msg, date: milliseconds};
query = connection.query('INSERT INTO messages SET ?', post, function(err, result) {
    update = connection.query(sql);
});

console.log(' usersend id:  ' +socket.userSend +'  user get:  ' + socket.userGet + ' ');
 socket.broadcast.to(socket.userGet).json.emit('incMsg',{'userSend': socket.userSend, 'name': socket.user, 'text': msg, 'time': time })

    });
  });
});
```

Запрос на выборку пользователя работает только в таком виде: `var sql = 'SELECT * FROM users';` и только если его вынести из socket.on(). Помогите пожалуйста разобраться

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Подскажите где вы взяли такой пример

```
 socket.on('connect_user', function(login,password, idUserGet) {
```

как вы делаете emit в этом случае ? (выведите `console.log(login,password, idUserGet)` чтобы точно убедиться)

насколько я понимаю формат socket.on -

```
socket.on('чтонибудь', function (data) {}); //на сервере
//------
socket.emit('чтонибудь',{"ключ": "значение"},successCallback); //на клиенте
```

Comment: log ничего не выводит потому, что запрос не работает, если запрос вынести из socket.on тогда запрос работает, но выдает ошибку, что login и password undefined, т.е не получает значения из базы. У меня проблема в том чтобы получить данные из базы о вошедшем пользователе (его id). С остальным уже как нибудь справлюсь.

Comment: Пример взят с хабры, уже неделю мучаюсь с ним.
http://habrahabr.ru/sandbox/51453/

Comment: ну вообще так можно делать конечно, но пример весьма странный надо сказать.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, буду пробовать.

Answer (score 0):

```
const getUserId = new Promise((resolve,reject)=>{

  const query = “select users.id from users where login = ? and password = ?”
  connection.query(query, [login,password],(err,result)=>{
    if(err) {reject(err)}
    if(result.length != 0) {resolve(result)} else {reject(“не подходящие логин/пароль”)}
  })

})

getUserId.then(
  (result)=>{
console.log(‘успех’,result)},
  (err)=>{console.log(‘ошибка’,err)}
)
```

Как вариант можна использовать знак вопроса ? И обернуть в промис для четкости.

Я бы рекомендовал сделать авторизацию на node.js приложении через express, express-session, express-mysql-session модули и потом взять сессионный ключ каждого пользователя что авторизовался и через socket io middleware функцию передать сокетам request.session.userId и при новом подключении, если пользователь уже авторизован (т.е socket.request.session.userId существует, для этого нужно будет добавить cookie-parser), создавать запись в таблице mysql в базе данных или перезаписывать при уже существующей записи, у каждого значения socketId userId для того что б через userId добывать socketId так как при каждом новом подключении socketId постоянно меняется, только после этого можна думать о реализации отправки приватных сообщений